# Enabling hibernate validation fail_fast in java config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I am using hibernate-validator 5.1.2.Final and Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE and want to make use of fail-fast so that when I have configured an annotation with multiple constraints, they are not all executed and only the first error message is returned.

```
@MultipartFileNotEmpty
@CsvFile
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface OrderCsv {

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

From looking at the [Hibernate Validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bootstrapping.html#section-provider-specific-settings) docs it appears I can enable fail_fast at a global level, but I am unsure how to enable this within Java config. My current hibernate configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages="uk.co.project")
public class HibernateConfig {

    final static String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    final static String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS);
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("datasource.password"));
        dataSource.setUrl(JDBC_URL + environment.getProperty("datasource.database"));
        dataSource.setInitialSize(10);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "uk.co.project.models" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {

        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I have tried adding `setProperty("hibernate.validator.fail_fast", "true");` to my `hibernateProperties` but that did not work. I would appreciate any pointers on how to enable fail_fast within my hibernate java config.

Comment: Have you tried removing the hibenate prefix from your hibernate properties?  I thought that the hibernate prefix was added to system properties to differentiate them from other properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"hibernate.validator.fail_fast" property is not the property of sessionFactory it is property for ValidatorFactory, you can try something like this:

```
@Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidatorFactory() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.getValidationPropertyMap().put("hibernate.validator.fail_fast", "true");
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make hibernate validator NOT stop when it is validating say a Set<String> when the validation fails for a value...in other words, is there a way I can validate the entire contents of a Collection regardless of how many validation failures are in there...represented as values that are ... invalid ? (thanks in advance...cause I am a newbie to hibernate validator)

Comment: It seems that it won't be applied with MockMvc in tests.